# rpi2 jessie python-can

Tags: can-bus

Trying to use python-can with raspi2 / jessie.
I installed/tried to install python-can via pip3 can package. Install looks to be ok, but python does not find module.
Tried searvhing google for help, but did not find any...

CAN interface with IXXAT usb to CAN v2 seems to be working after compiling kernel module. (can-utils work and socket is up)

> pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sudo pip3 install can
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): can in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages.
>   Cleaning up...
>   pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $
>
> pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages $ ls
>   can-2.0.egg-info  libcan
>   pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages $
>
> pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python3.4 j1939CANlogger.py 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "j1939CANlogger.py", line 2, in 
>       import can
>   ImportError: No module named 'can'
>   pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $

System Info:

> pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages $ uname -a
>   Linux raspberrypi 4.9.80-v7+ #1 SMP Thu Jan 3 21:30:06 EET 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
>   pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages $
>
> pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages $ python3 --version.
>   Python 3.4.2
>   pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages $

Based on first answer:

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip3 install python-can
>     Downloading/unpacking python-can
>     Downloading python_can-3.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (123kB): 123kB downloaded
>     Cleaning up...
>     Exception:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2595, in _dep_map
>       return self.**dep_map
>     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2457, in        __getattr**
>       raise AttributeError(attr)
>   AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map..... lot more errors....

So I was able to download python-can package, but not able install. :-(
I assume that I have somekind of dependency issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did

```
sudo pip3 install can
```

which apperantly installs a [filesystem backup utility](https://pypi.org/project/can/).

You should do

```
sudo pip3 install python-can
```

to install [python-can](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/). Then you should be able to find the module.

For your python-can installation issue, try upgrading pip first:

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to install python-can first, but install did not work. Then I got confused in the names.... :-(

Comment: @Antero Salojärvi I have suggested a possible solution in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! I try that after I get rpi to boot up again. I noticed that I had python3 and python3.4 installed. Removing those caused my rpi fail to boot. I will upgrade to fresh installation of strech. Maybe my problems is solved with that.

Comment: I managed to make Jessie to boot up again, installed python3.4 again and upgraded pip3. --> Problem solved!  Thank you for support!

Comment: Sure, you are welcome! :-)